# Protractor click element until it's not disabled

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to write a test, my results are displayed on few pages, I can go to next page by click button, if there is no next page button is disabled, how could i achieve it with protractor? My code fails with `allocation failed` error

```
while(element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.nextPage()"]')).isEnabled())
{
element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.nextPage()"]')).click();
}
```

I have also tried with recursive function called on `isEnabled().then` but it also does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use recursion here:

```
var nextPage = function () {
    if (element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.nextPage()"]')).isEnabled()) {
        element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.nextPage()"]')).click();
        nextPage(); // next page
    }
    else {
        return; // the element is not enabled, last page
    }
}
```

and just call it once in your code, if the page is angular (which i assume it is) it will be correct.

The while will not work here, same for "for", since it can't look forward, so it doesn't know how many times the while will be called, hence the `allocation failed` error.

Comment: looks like i have accept it too early, weel function works nice after i have added `.click().then...` but it seems to be jump into infinite recursive calls so it never ends

Comment: you could try and exchange `if (element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.nextPage()"]')).isEnabled()) {`
 with `element(by.css('[ng-click="vm.nextPage()"]')).isEnabled().then(function (value) { if (value) { ...`